# What is the correct Rust inline assembly format?

Tags: rust

How do you get the new inline assembly format to work with rust? I would like to have a function that calls outb.

```
unsafe fn outb(value: u8, port: u16) {
    asm!(
        "outb {0}, {1}",
        in(reg_byte) value,
        in(reg_abcd) port,
     );
 }
```

This was the only version that almost produced code. There error message was:

```
error: invalid operand for instruction

   |
29 |         "outb {0}, {1}",
   |          ^
   |
note: instantiated into assembly here
--> <inline asm>:2:2
   |
2  |     outb dil, rax
   |     ^
```

Comment: This is x86?  The `out` instruction only accepts the data in `al` and the port in `dx` or immediate; no other register combinations can be encoded.

Comment: Yes (I have the asm manual), but if you add those two registers is says "note: explicit register arguments cannot be used in the asm template" (ie "al" and "dx" resp, not edx nor rdx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using AT&T syntax, but the new `asm!` defaults to Intel's. You can still use AT&T but you have to add `options(att_syntax)`.

Then, take a look at [how this instruction can be used](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_222.html). What you need is to resolve to `OUT DX, AL` (`outb %al, %dx` in AT&T), no other registers of these sizes are allowed.

So you cannot use register classes at all:

```
    asm!(
        "outb %al, %dx",
        in("dx") port,
        in("al") value,
        options(att_syntax)
     );
```

Or in Intel syntax:

```
    asm!(
        "out dx, al",
        in("dx") port,
        in("al") value,
     );
```